# Java applets crashing in 14.04 and 14.10

Tags: 14.04, java, 14.10, icedtea

[PhET simulations](https://phet.colorado.edu) (java applets) crash in 14.04 (and in 14.10 [update]) after execution. Icedtea starts loading the app and gets to 100%. Then it crashes. I get an error message to use the console to clear my cache and retry. This doesn't work. It just cashes again.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

This issue is occurring on 2 computers, one running Ubuntu, the other Xubuntu. The PhET simulations are running fine on 12.04, 13.10 and Windows.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently openJDK is broken in 14.04 (& 14.10). This problem is fixed by installing oracle java 7:

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

To allow FireFox to run the applets you also need IcedTea Java Web Start:

```
    sudo apt-get install icedtea-netx-common
```

PS I also installed icedtea-netx and that did **not** work. Only icedtea-netx-common worked for me (Ubuntu 14.10).

Everything works now!