# Java is not working in any browser

Tags: firefox, java, openjdk, icedtea

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 , and I've used the 12th edition and 13th and it was always the same problem for me, java is NOT working on any of my browser : all applets aren't functional, I can't login to some websites and I can't get any of the codepens to work (all I get is "Loading...........") ..etc

I downloaded and installed OpenJDK 1.7.0 and that's what I get when I use the

> java -version

in terminal:

```
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

I have installed IcedTea using the software center

I'm in Syria, So I can't use Oracle.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try enabling java in your browser.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, but here is the thing:
I can't find any JAVA plugins on Chrome. and on firefox I can find IcedTea Plugin but No JAVA.. how is this possible when I've already downloaded Java?

Comment: Java pulgin for firefox is icedTea it enable java to run on firefox

Comment: for more https://www.java.com/en/download/help/browser_activate_plugin.xml

Comment: well IcedTea is enabled but still no result

Comment: and why I can't find a Java plugin in my Chrome Plugins page although I have Java Downloaded and Installed already?

Comment: If you install 32 bit along with 64 bit java it will work.

Comment: downloaded & installed it but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Just install the 32bit version of OpenJDK / IcedTea

That should do the trick, most browsers are still 32bit even when the OS is 64bit

However from experience I do know some websites Java Apps are picky and don't like non Sun/Oracle Java Runtimes.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me get mine running on 12.04, after nothing else helped, was to make sure I had everything installed. I had IcedTea Web Control Panel, OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime and OpenJDK Java 6 Runtime. But what I didn't have but needed was the "Icedtea Java Plugin" which I installed via the Software Center. Upon restarting my browser (Firefox) I was able to run the Java applets from the PHeT site.

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution offered here: [Java applets crashing in 14.04 and 14.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454155/java-applets-crashing-in-14-04)

It worked in Ubuntu 14.10 to allow PhET java-based simulations to run. The Java that is in the Ubuntu 14.10 repositories didn't work with PhET but the Oracle Java does (as of 2015/2/3).